# Why is $\tan(33^\circ)-\tan(27.7^\circ)=0.124$?

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers

I was helping someone do a trigonometry word problem, and we computed the following thing by calculator.
$$\tan(33^\circ)-\tan(27.7^\circ)=0.124$$
I was pretty surprised to get a rational number back here. Does anyone have any insight as to why that happened? Is this more unlikely than I imagine? Or, do you think the textbook authors are conspiring to make things work out that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equation is not true. It's not even close; the next few digits are

$$ 0.1243958558\ldots $$

You can see this, for example, in [this wolfram alpha calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(33%20degrees)%20-%20tan(27.7%20degrees)%20to%2010%20decimal%20places).

Presumably, whatever calculator you used decided to round the result to the same level of precision you supplied. For example, [wolfram alpha (currently) does that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(33%20degrees)%20-%20tan(27.7%20degrees)).

Comment: Can we say something about the (ir)rationality of this quantity, though? That would be more useful information.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг what's there to say?  There's no reason to assume it is rational.  By arbitrary values alone it's execeding unlikely to have an rational or irrational significance.

Comment: @fleablood Merely as a collector's item. I know such a quantity is insignificant.